# MacBook User Needs to Download Ubuntu to a USB Stick to Install on Another PC

Tags: boot, system-installation, usb

I need to find out if there's a way on a MacBook computer to make a bootable USB stick which as the Ubuntu ISO install files on it to then run on a another PC to have it install.  I don't want Ubuntu installed on my MacBook but just need to get the Ubuntu install files to a bootable USB stick which is mounted on my MacBook as I don't have a Windows PC to make it happen.

Is this at all possible?  My old Dell Windows PC hard drive died and I thought this would be a good opportunity to install Ubuntu to the system rather than reloading windows back on the PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. You need `Etcher`, follow instructions [here](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#1-overview)

Comment: Adriaan, Thank you very much for the info. I was able to get the USB Thumb drive built, bootable and Ubuntu ISO setup on it to allow me to rebuild my PC. 

Comment: Great! Could you please click on "accept answer"?